# Azure AD B2C - Unauthenticated error while creating a tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

I've been trying to create an Azure AD B2C tenant, but I am receiving an 'Unauthenticated' error while doing so.

- I am the owner of the azure account and no one else is using it.
- I have a single Active Directory tenant with a single directory.
- My subscription has registered the necessary resource provider - Microsoft.AzureActiveDirectory.
- Restrict non-admin users from creating tenants AD option is set to 'no' (shouldn't matter, since I am the owner of the account and have global admin role?).
- Added the 'Tenant Creator' role to myself, did not help (again, shouldn't matter since i already have the global admin role?).
- I have tried to create a new regular AD tenant, to verify if I would receive the same error as in the case of B2C, but the regular AD tenant is being created without any problems.

Can't really understand it, since if it was a permission related problem, the error should say 'Unauthorized' instead of 'Unauthenticated'? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Same here, it worked last week. It could be an Azure Portal temporary issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue yesterday. Looks like the issue is now fixed. I couldn't find any documentation of what the issue was.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).